# Is it possible to get the total unread mail count with Priority Inbox?

Tags: gmail

With Google's recent changes to Gmail inboxes, it seems that if I pick "Priority Inbox" as my preferred view, I can only see the number of unread important email in the sidebar:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can (hopefully) see from my heavily-blurred and resized screenshot, the sidebar says `Inbox (5)`, but there are many unread email in `Everything Else`.

Is there a way to get the total unread mail count now, similar to how it used to be where `Priority Inbox (X)` would give the number of unread important emails and `Inbox (Y)` would give the total unread count?

Comment: You should check out the new Metro style theme. Its really nice! :)

Comment: @Barry Which one is that? There's no "Metro" in my themes list. Is that the "Preview" theme? I hate it with a fiery passion. :)

Comment: No not preview. `Preview (Dense)`!! :-S *shuffles off*

Comment: @Barry Too much eye-searing white in that theme for my tastes. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a setting for this, you need to:

- Click `Mail Settings` from the cog menu
- Click the `Inbox` tab
- Ensure that the **Inbox Type** is set to `Priority Inbox`
- In the **Inbox unread count** section select the radio button named **Unread items in the inbox**
- Save your changes

[image: Gmail Inbox Settings]

Comment: Within the Mail settings => Inbox tab I had to click "Reset Priority Inbox to default configuration" to get the Inbox unread count section to show up